# TimerTask runs one more time after I call timer.cancel() method

Tags: java, timer, timertask

TimerTask runs one more time after I call timer.cancel() method. 
I don't need TimerMethod to be executed after I call stopBusTimer() method.

Can somebody explain why is it happening?

```
busTimer = new Timer();
    busTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod(mSelectedRoute);
        }
    }, 0, Consts.BUS_TIMER_INTERVAL);


 private void stopBusTimer() {
    if (busTimer != null) {
        busTimer.cancel();
        busTimer.purge();     
        busTimer = null;
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "stop BusTimer");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cancel` method will stop all following executions, but not the current one. It your method execution takes a long time, then it is possible by the time you call `cancel`, the method has already begun executing.

The best way to make sure the method does not execute is to call `cancel` from within the `run()` function itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood how it works. Now I need to figure out how to cancel the httprequest I am sending inside of run() function.