# TimerTask doesn't stop immediately after timer.cancel() being called from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask

I have an applet to do following things:
Main thread and thread t1 request something cyclically, a button will stop both.

```
public class HttpsConn {
    private static boolean stop = false;
    private static Timer t = null;

    public static void main(String[] arg)  {
        t = new Timer();
        A a = new A();
        t.schedule(a, 0, 1000);
        B b = new B();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(b);
        t1.start();
    }
    static class A extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (stop)
                t.cancel();     //this.cancel();
            System.out.println("something to do");
        }
    }
    static class B extends A implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("simulate an operation from Swing Applet (click RESET button) to interrupt the thread.");
             stop = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I except the result:

```
something to do
simulate an operation from Swing Applet (click RESET button) to interrupt the thread.
```

What I get:

```
something to do
simulate an operation from Swing Applet (click RESET button) to interrupt the thread.
something to do
```

I find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651832/timertask-runs-one-more-time-after-i-call-timer-cancel-method), the answer says *call cancel from within the run()*, but it seems not work here.
Then how to avoid the unexpected running? 
And what's the difference between `t.cancel()` and `this.cancel()` on the line with comment? They lead to same result.
Thanks!

Comment: It appears the cancel is working fine though. It cancels, then it prints the line, as it should.

Comment: As to your subsequent question. `this.cancel()` cancels the TimerTask which means the Timer could still function. t.cancel() cancels the timer.

Comment: Also, I would like to discourage you from using an applet.

Comment: @matt I concur. But do you have an idea how to stop the thread before the additional line is printed?

Comment: You don't want to "stop the thread" just use an appropriate if(stop){ this.cancel(); return;} Then nothing else in the run method runs.

Comment: If you cancel the timer, then no scheduled tasks will be executed anymore. If you cancel the task, then *that task* will not be scheduled for execution anymore. In this case it doesn't make a difference since you don't have any other tasks going to your timer.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I get it. They happened to be the same in my case. I am afraid I used wrong word 'applet' here. English is not my native language and 'applet' is described as something like small, simple, concise program in the translation tool (mainly runs in web page). Is the explanation comprehensive?

Comment: Sure, applet is also the name of an old way to distribute java programs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `A` is scheduled to run with an initial delay of `0` and subsequent delays of `1` second.

The first `something to do` is the first time it executes after a `0` delay. The `stop` flag has not been set so it just prints and exits.

One second later it is invoked again by the `Timer`. It checks for the `stop` flag, cancels the timer (because `B` has executed and set it) and prints a second `something to do`. It should not run again as the timer task has now been cancelled.

To avoid this seemingly strange behavior you could use something like:

```
        if (!stop) {
            System.out.println("something to do");
        } else {
            t.cancel();     //this.cancel();
        }
```

Remember that `cancel` only cancels the `Timer`, it does not abort the execution of the `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks. It looks so easy in this way :) . Then can you help me on  my 2nd question? @matt commented my post but I still cannot figure out the difference between timer being cancelled and timertask being cancelled. If the timer is terminated the timertask will not continue; if the timertask is terminated the timer can do nothing even it does not die. So? any difference?

Comment: @feng - Your `TimerTask` (which you call `a`) is executed each time the the `Timer` decides to do so, under the control of the parameters passed in the `schedule` call. It runs normally and terminates each time it is invoked through it's `run` method. The `Timer` will continue to call it until it is stopped. I hope that makes things clearer.